# Get an element from a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

i have vector of pointers: `std::vector<Customer*> customersList`
Now i want to get one of the elements and make my operations on him.
i'm not sure that i know how, my guess was:

```
Customer* source = restaurant.getCustomer(cust);
```

the problem is that i don't know if in c++ it will create new object or i will just get a reference to him.
There is my getter method:

```
Customer* Table::getCustomer(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < customersList.size(); ++i) {
        if (customersList[i]->getId() == id)
            return customersList[i];
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It copies the pointer, but not the pointed object.

Comment: Great so i'm not make any copy of the object himself, am i right?

Comment: Yup, it'll point to the original object.

Comment: If your source is a pointer (or vector of pointers) and you're returning a pointer, there will be no new object created unless you specifically go out of your way to create one.   For example, calling a `clone()` function that deliberately allocates a new object and returns its address.   The default behaviour is that the object is not deep copied (i.e. a new object is not created).

Comment: Thank you very much thats solve my question :)

Comment: Pointers are objects too, that's why you can have a `std::vector` of them.

Comment: I have a follow-up Question in the same problem. what if I want to get a reference to the vector i get from std::vector<Customer*> customersList. I mean that i dont want to create a different vector, i just want a reference to handle the vector elements

Answer (score 5):

The member function will return a copy of the pointer, i.e. the `Customer` object itself is not copied, only the reference to it. Modifying the returned `Customer*` will result in modifications of the pointee (the underlying object).

Note that you also want to use the `<algorithm>` header, specifically `std::find_if`.

```
const auto  customer = std::find_if(customerList.begin(), customerList.end(),
    [id](const Customer* c){ return c->getId() == id; });

return customer == customerList.cend() ? nullptr : *customer;
```

Comment: Thank you. what if i want to make changes on that object, const not make it forbidden?

Comment: The `const auto customer` forbids any changes to the iterator named `customer`. The object it points to can be modified.